# tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
chrome.tabs.update(null, {url: 'https://example.com/'});
});
```

above code work when I trigger when my address bar have something, means I'm at any web pages, but when I trigger when my address bar is blank, I got below error :

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
    at Object.callback
```

Comment: That's a strange logic to begin with: `executeScript`, _then_ update the tab. What are you achieving here?

Comment: @Xan why? I inject jquery.js and my content script, to communite with the DOM, then I want to continue to do something with my popup.js. Above code worked when my tab loaded some web pages, not when the tab is blank.

Comment: Well, in your simplified code you inject jQuery only, and even then your content script only has time for synchronous operations; anything async will enter a race condition with the tab navigating away and the content script will be wiped as soon as the navigation commits.

Comment: @Xan I don't get the async and sync part, are you saying there might be a problem with my flow above?

Comment: Yes! This is precisely what I'm saying. The content script won't persist after navigation, and has little time to do anything before. Whether it succeeds or not depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Yes but it's fine in my case. I just injected something to get some values of DOM elements, and pass them back to my popup.js.

Comment: How do you pass them back?

Comment: @xan, in my content script I do like this `chrome.extension.sendRequest({message: myVar});`

Comment: Then this **can fail** to process before the tab is updated. You should update the tab from the message listener, not `executeScript` callback.

Answer (score 2):

- Normally (see also [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) in docs) it's not possible to inject scripts into tabs with `chrome://` urls because [the allowed schemes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) are `<scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp'`.

  **In Chrome before v61** it was still possible to inject into the content frame of the New Tab page, where the "blank address bar" you mentioned is represented internally as `chrome://newtab/`. For example the main frame has an address like this: https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8 (use Network panel in devtools to inspect the urls). So your `manifest.json` would have `"permissions": ["tabs", "https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab*"],`
- Alternatively you can enable `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag, however this is hardly useful as Chrome will show a warning each start.

Comment: I see, seems like I have to do a validation to check whether it's chrome:// or it has some pages loaded. How to do that? get the browser URL?

Comment: @AaronMusktin Do not try to guess [which URLs are unscriptable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30261291/934239). Instead, check `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the `executeScript`'s callback and fail gracefully.

Comment: @AaronMusktin, You can check the URL, but even still, you would still need to handle possible errors eg when the tab is closed by the user.

Comment: You handle `chrome.runtime.lastError` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951