# Which URLs are restricted to operate on with Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

All chrome:// prefixed URLs (e.g. chrome://extensions/ ) and all Chrome Web Store URLs (e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb ) are somehow restricted to work with.

Is there some complete list of these restricted URLs?

Comment: I answered here in detail, but can't use it as a duplicate target without an upvote/accept: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30261291/934239

Comment: Thank You, that answered my question. If somebody from Google Chrome team is reading this - I suggest to add this information somewhere to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to update or add sort of meta-title to the question "Chrome extension open new tab on new tab" so it will contain the actual question (and be more user-friendly, make sense and be indexable)?

Comment: If this question is kept as-is, it provides a good enough discovery path.