# Content script doesn't support chrome settings page (url : chrome://history/ etc. )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am working with a chrome extension . I want to inject js script in all tab. I am using this manifest.json :

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "src/background/background.min.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/128.png",
        "default_title": "ABC",
        "default_popup": "src/browser_action/index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["./src/inject/inject.min.js"],
        "css": ["./css/inject.min.css"],
        "all_frames": true
    }]
}
```

And my inject.js is like this :

```
(function() {
   console.log("Hello");
});
```

I am getting all log from all tab except the tab of the chrome setting (eg : chrome://extensions/:id , chrome://history etc). 
Am I missing something in manifest.json or chrome disables the feature of injection in settings page ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It this a personal or public extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you can't inject code into `chrome://` pages. They contain control elements / code that can modify the browser in ways that an extension is not allowed to.

Chrome resolves this by simply [not allowing permissions to be set for `chrome://` URLs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), and `<all_urls>` does not include it.

However, you could use [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) to replace some of them (well, History page at least) completely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an another queries , can you help me ? 
This injection is not also working in this page https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en-US .
But this should matches with "https://*/*" pattern .

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259634/chrome-extension-open-new-tab-on-new-tab/30261291