# Chrome extension is not loaded in some pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created chrome extension for better productivity using `content script` but it's not being loaded on pages like

```
chrome://settings/
chrome-extension://some/extension.html
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions
```

I believe it's some security measure but I couldn't find any official statement.

Is there a way to get additional permission for these pages or somehow got white-listed?
If it's not possible I would really like to provide official link with explanation in my description (**or at least list all not supported pages**).

EDIT:
My [manifest.json file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3390224/StackOverflow/manifest.json) contains permission: `"<all_urls>"` and `content_scripts` matches all url: `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`

Comment: Can you provide your manifest file. You can also check if your script has eval or something dangerous.

Comment: You can use search and find many existing answers that explain why these urls are restricted. Or you can check source code yourself: [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/permissions/permissions_data.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1478143038&l=87) and [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/chrome_extensions_client.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1478143038&l=234)

Comment: @wOxxOm well you could provide at least one to help me...

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for those links, but I really cannot find any answer answering my questions...

Comment: I use google with something like "stackoverflow chrome extension on webstore urls" and the top link is [Chrome Extension Content Script on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](//stackoverflow.com/q/11613371) and for chrome urls: [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19042857) As for the full list, CWS is the only excluded website as you can see in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed hard to find official statements.

- Canonical question regarding CWS scripting:
  [Chrome Extension Content Script on https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613371/chrome-extension-content-script-on-https-chrome-google-com-webstore)

  As wOxxOm mentions, `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/*` is the **only** website exception.
- Canonical question on `chrome://` scripting:
  [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension)

  This is also reflected in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns): `"<all_urls>"` only allows *"any URL that uses a permitted scheme"*, `chrome://` not being one of the permitted schemes.

**Edit: found a [nice summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30261291/934239) I made earlier.**

It's highly unlikely that you would be granted a whitelist for either of those.

> APIs that require whitelisting are dangerous, and we try to avoid them as much as possible.<sup>[[source]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575969#c4)</sup>