# Extension affects another web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html

I am having some problems creating Chrome extensions. The code affects all pages that are open in Chrome, how can I solve it?

My *manifest.json*:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Merch Tools 41studio",
    "description": "report app",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js", "assets/js/background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "assets/image/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js", "assets/js/highcharts.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: don't target "all webs"

Comment: Can you tell me, how to make it?

Comment: can you show me what you've done? specifically the manifest

Comment: `{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Merch Tools 41studio",
  "description": "report app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js","assets/js/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/image/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": [
       "assets/js/jquery.min.js",
       "assets/js/highcharts.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: `"matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]` - well, you specifically match everything here

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the list of domains your content scripts run on by changing the `matches` property in `content_scripts`. Having a `"http://*/*","https://*/*"` means the content script runs on all http and https websites. Rather you could specify a list of websites that you want the extension to run on.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Merch Tools 41studio",
  "description": "report app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js", "assets/js/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/image/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http:/yoursite.com/*"], // Change this to the sites you want your extension to run on
    "js": ["assets/js/jquery.min.js", "assets/js/highcharts.js"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: my apps runing on new tabs, not only one site [chrome-extension://]

Comment: So you don't want it to run on any site, but on the new tab page?

Comment: I don't think a content script will run on that page. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39267314/5894241)